# Prevent first fetch api with no parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a `const [id, setId] = useState` in context, which will be updated id by `setId` in `useEffect` after fetch API. Then, i have a component, which use this id as parameters to fetch API (this fetch is called in useEffect). It works but in the first time when `id = null`, it shows `404 (Not Found)` because `id = null`. How do i fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If id==null then return?

Comment: In your render method please have this check if(id != null){... your_render logic}
else return </>

Comment: thank @Lonewolf, im so stupid :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this render method logic. You have to render something initially when the component is mounted

```
render() {
if(id!= null){
// your_render_logic
}else{
return </>
}
}
```